# XNA Rectangle.Center not returning expected value

Tags: c#, xna, center

I have a rectangle with `{X:100 Y:60 Width:37 Height:58}`

`Rectangle.Center` is returning `{X:118 Y:89}`

I expect it to return `{X:15.5 Y:44.5}` (not specifically including decimals) which is half of the rectangles width and height.

I can't figure out what the heck it's doing here. So simple question. What's up with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is returning the correct result. Why would you expect X=15.5 and Y=44.5? Rectangle.Center will return the center of the rectangle (as one would expect). The center is equal to:

```
{X + (width/2), Y + (height/2)}
```

Plugging in the given values results in:

```
{100 + (37/2), 60 + (58/2)}
{100 + 18.5, 60 + 29}
{118.5, 89}
```

Since Rectangles use `int` however, the 118.5 is rounded to 118 resulting in a final answer of:

```
{118, 89}
```

Please expand on your question as to why you would expect any kind of different result?

Comment: oh wow my math was wrong.. It's late, I'm tired.. >.< I could've and should've figured that out.. Thanks.